# gcc on MacOS: Strange threading error

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, pthreads

I'm porting a program that already works in Windows and Linux to MacOS (Lion), and I'm encountering a very strange issue.

I have a very long function (about 3000 lines of C++ code), which runs fine if I call it directly from my main thread.

However, if I create a separate pthread and call the same function from there, I get crashes. Even if the main thread is not doing anything (Sleep). The crash always occurs at exactly the same place (so it's not a timing issue), about 2000 lines into this function; if I remove a few lines of code it just moves down a bit.

With gcc 4.2 the error occurs in debug mode, and disappears if I enable some optimizations (but with -O3 it occurs again). With gcc 4.9, it only occurs in release mode if I enable -O2 or -O3. So, I'm now trying to figure out what happens with gcc 4.2 (since I can reproduce it in debug mode).

To make things even weirder: I have 2 booleans (loudness_on and en), and the crash occurs in the following line:

```
bool en2 = loudness_on && en;
```

Removing either loudness_on or en from this line stops the error from occurring. (It moves a few lines down, well below the point where en2 goes out of scope).

I've run valgrind and it reports no errors.

I would suspect a stack issue (maybe threads have a smaller stack?) but gdb reports something that does not seem to be stack related at all:

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000109588ec7
[Switching to process 12928 thread 0x4203]
0x00000001002e4809 in ParSet::refresh_parameters () at /Users/User/BUILD/Param.cpp: 3017
3017     bool en2 = loudness_on && en;
```

Any idea what might be happening here would be very welcome. I'll try to split the function into smaller parts later, to see if that helps (it might if it's a stack issue).

Comment: "*... if I remove a few lines of code it just moves down a bit.*" you want to say "*... up a bit.*" won't you?

Comment: Are `loudness_on` and `en` thread local variables or are the global? It the latter did you protected them against concurrent access?

Comment: I do not really get it: "*Removing either loudness_on or en from this line stops the error from occurring.*" So it stops occurring, good. But wait, it does not "*(It moves a few lines down, well below the point where en2 goes out of scope).*" What moves down? The line where the error occurrs?

Comment: Sorry for the unclarity. Both variables are local variables of the function - that's what makes it so strange.  And I can view their values in the debugger without issues.

Comment: And what I mean is that the code still crashes a few lines further in the function.

Comment: Splitting yhe function did not help, it still crashes at nearly (but not exactly) the same location.

Comment: For the sake of ease of debugging try to use an environment, where you can reproduce the error with optimisation turned **off**. gdb might show quiet unusable info regarding where in the code the program is, if the binary was build with optimisation turned on.

Comment: However: statements like "*it still crashes at nearly (but not exactly) the same location*" are a bit to vage for us to help you. Expecially without seeing any code ... :-(

Comment: @alk that's why I used gcc 4.2 - I could reproduce it in debug mode. About vague statements: See my answer below. The "reason" for the crash was apparently lack of stack space; the code itself was huge (function of 3000 lines using macros), so I could hardly post that...

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: If I create the pthread with a larger stack it no longer crashes. I must say that the gdb-warning was very unclear and didn't seem to point at running out of stack space at all (a debugger should be able to detect this right?)

Anyway, this code solves it:

```
size_t stacksize = 0;
pthread_attr_t attr;
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_getstacksize(&attr, &stacksize);
pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attr, max(stacksize, 1024 * (1024  + 512));

pthread_t wxmt;
pthread_create(&wxmt, &attr, mainThread, NULL);
```

As it turns out, the default stack size for pthreads on a Mac is only 512 kB (on Linux it's 8 MB!) - this code increases it to 1.5 MB (1 would probably have sufficed, but since the errors that occur are really strange and I want to avoid having to do another search in the future, I'm giving it a bit more.)